# Python script to parse/convert latex string into utf-8?

Tags: python, utf-8, latex, tex

I result being retrieved from the db, on this form:

```
(86, 'B{\\u{a}}beanu', 'Alexandru-Ionut') 
(101, "Dosil Su{\\'a}rez", 'Alvaro') 
(119, 'Massafferri', "Andr{\\'e}") 
(161, 'M{\\"u}ller', 'Anke-Susanne')
```

I'd like to decode this characters from latex to unicode, e.g. utf8 (it will be shown on a webpage).
But I can't install modules on the server, e.g. [latexCodec](http://latexcodec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation).

I coudn`t find scripts that worked for me on web, not even this on stackoverflow. Are there any script for work this out?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your server is set up, you might be able to install a user copy of `latexcodec` - for example, by using `pip install --user` or by extracting the tarball into the appropriate `pythonx.y` folder in `~/.local/lib`. If even that isn't an option, you *can* in the worst case still keep a static copy of it in your project directory. None of these methods will be handled by your , but that doesn't seem likely to be a big problem here - the [latexcodec git respository](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/latexcodec/) hasn't received any update in nearly a year.

Note that using `latexcodec` will parse the latex into *unicode*, not utf-8 encoded bytes - but this is almost certainly what you actually want, and if it really isn't, you can re-encode to utf8 from there.